# After upgrading to Ubuntu 13.04, should I stick with NVIDIA 310 driver or should I change it to 313 driver?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, steam

After upgrading to Ubuntu 13.04 (64-bit edition), I checked the "Additional drivers" configuration and I noticed a new 313 NVIDIA driver entry. As a Steam user, I had previously changed from the open source driver to 310 NVIDIA driver.

There is no "Recommended" option and there is no "Help" button to get more information, so what should I do?

Thank you.

Comment: Whatever driver works best for you ;)

Comment: where is the download link for the driver?????

Answer (score 3):

There is a huge difference in gaming performance between the 304 and the 310 one. I have a GeForce GTX 660Ti and i'm using version 310. Also tested version 313 but couldn't see any difference at all. After digging around the nvidia.com site, it seems the 313 version just adds support for the newest high-end cards like the GTX Titan.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I was sellecting each of those drivers (304, 310, 313 - current and updates) and they all work the same. I didn't understand the differences, but you can research at nvidia forums and official nvidia sites - higher number means newer driver, ie. possible performance increase (usually only in the games).

Comment: But I do not understand why adding several driver options if the user has to do research which is the "right" one.

Comment: They are all the right driver, i suggest the highest version that works for your system, waiting on the 319.23 driver to be available outside of the xorg edgers ppa and in a stable ppa

Answer (score 1):

Some of the newer Nvidia drivers will have support for the newer chip sets and have performance tweaks . However if you have older Nvidia cards they may no longer be supported by the newer driver so check on the Nvidia site and research the driver and ensure its compatible with your hardware.

http://www.nvidia.co.uk/object/linux-display-amd64-313.09-driver-uk.html

Shows the fixes